# Noise characters in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table.Diagnosis([DESCRIPTION]) VALUES('person's')
```

How can insert it?

Comment: what does this have to do with C#? You used the "C#" tag. Does this question relate specifically to passing in a value from C# code? That piece of info is critical to getting a correct answer here. Meaning, there are currently 3 answers and if this question is specific to sending data from C#, then @Steve 's answer is the only correct one. If not dealing with C#, then the other two (which are basically the same answer) are correct.

Comment: You are giving an _"example"_, but don't say what for. You refer to inserting _"it"_, without saying what _"it"_ is. Your title mentions _"noise characters"_. Do you refer to the apostrophe? Is your question how a T-SQL string literal can contain apostrophes?

Answer (score 6):

`'Person's'` should actually be `'Person''s'`.  SQL Server thinks the string ends with that second single quote, so you have to "escape" it with an additional quote.

So your code as-is thinks it's trying to insert `"Person"` and anything after this is gibberish to SQL Server.

You'll need to modify your statement to the following:

```
INSERT INTO table.Diagnosis([DESCRIPTION]) VALUES('person''s')
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have tagged this as C# I think that you want to set this value through code.
If this is the case then you probably have a string concatenation that ignores the presence of the single quote.

Something like this

```
string descValue = "person's";
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO table.Diagnosis([DESCRIPTION]) VALUES(" + descValue +")";
```

To avoid this problem you should use a parameterized query like this

```
string descValue = "person's";
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO table.Diagnosis([DESCRIPTION]) VALUES(@desc)";
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
{
   cnn.Open();
   cmd.AddWithValue("@desc", descValue);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Using a parameterized query shifts the job to use your values to the database engine that now could correctly prepare your values and not blindly run the sql *as is*. This is true also for other types of values like decimals and dates. Last but not least, a parameterized query is the only way to avoid an [Sql Injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: While I believe a parameterized query is overkill for inserting a constant string, you're making a good point. However, `descValue` should be set to `"person's"`, not `"'person's'"`: I think we can assume that the OP got the outermost apostrophes right (string literal delimiters), I suppose s/he doesn't want to insert them as part of the string value.

Comment: @stakx right about the descValue (a copy/paste error). For the query, well if it is a costant perhaps you are right, but I think that this is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Escape single quote with an additional single

```
INSERT INTO table.Diagnosis([DESCRIPTION]) VALUES('person''s')
```